# Solidity error basic programme

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-deployment, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am not able to find the error to this problem Can anyone please help me with it

It is showing that hasDeceased function is having some error...  Not able to access the function ...

[image: Error]

Comment: Hi, I would like to try and help you, but could you post a bit more info? A screenshot might be ideal here.

Comment: Maybe you sould check if they have an inheritance before calling the ln 40 inside hasDeceased